# Extending Craft Commerce admin templates

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

I would like to add an option to the gear menu seen below in Craft Commerce, is it possible to extend those templates ?

The idea is to create a plugin to export the selected orders to a CSV file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented on the Commerce site (yet), but Commerce does have `commerce_addProductActions` and `commerce_addOrderActions` hooks that a [plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) could latch onto to add its own custom actions to the Order and Product index pages.

Virtually identical to the [add(Element)Actions](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#element-hooks) hooks that Craft provides for its elements.